# Quadratic relationship between amount of light and intensity

Tags: experimental-physics, spectroscopy, intensity

In a spectroscopy experiment, we were able to control the amount of light shining onto a sample by adjusting two small slits.
By investigating the relationship between slit width and the intensity of light detected by the photoconductor, we found a quadratic relationship, i.e. doubling the slit width resulted in four times the intensity of light detected.
The only explanation that comes to mind for me is that this has something to do with the well-known result that the intensity of a light wave is proportional to the square of the amplitude of the electric field vector, $I \propto |E|^2$, and that by doubling the slit width we are in some sense doubling the number of electric field vectors.
However, I feel that this may be a serious oversimplification of the problem.
Any other suggestions as to why we got this result or improvements to my answer would be appreciated.